# I want my form to search when i press enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

This is my code so far..

```
<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
var searchBarOpen = false;

function closeSearch() {
    if(searchBarOpen) {
        $j('#navbar-typeahead').hide();
        $j('#navbar-removelabel').hide();
        $j('.navbar-nav').show();
        searchBarOpen = false;
    }
}

function openSearch() {
    if(!searchBarOpen) {
        $j('.navbar-nav').hide();
        $j('#navbar-typeahead').show();
        $j('#navbar-removelabel').show();
        searchBarOpen = true;
    }
}

$j('#navbar-removelabel').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(searchBarOpen) {
        $j('#navbar-typeahead').val('');
        closeSearch();
    }
});

$j('#navbar-searchlabel').click(function(e) {
    if(!searchBarOpen) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        openSearch();
    } else {

        if($j('#navbar-typeahead').val() != "") {
            // Getting search results
        } else {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            closeSearch();
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Now i am not able to get this form to search when i press enter..
i tried to use :

```
<script>    
function enter () {
    document.onkeypress = function (enter) {
    if (enter.keyCode == 13) {
        $('.enter').submit();
         }
    };
};
</script>
```

Here is my HTML,

```
<form role="search" class="navbar-searchform navbar-right" method="get" action="/">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Uw zoektermen..." id="navbar-typeahead" class="form-control enter" data-provide="typeahead"></input>
    </div>
    <button id="navbar-removelabel" class="btn bnt-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">
        </span>
    </button>
    <button id="navbar-searchlabel" class="btn bnt-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">
        </span>
    </button>
</form>
```

But i am not able to get it working. Can someone please  help me?
i cant figure out what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Does your form contain a class named `enter`? Also, why don't you post your HTML page here so that we can understand what your Javascript code does?

Comment: Yes it does contain a class named enter

Comment: `class="navbar-searchform navbar-right"` — No, it doesn't.

Comment: now it does. 
`<form role="search" class="navbar-searchform navbar-right enter" method="get" action="/">`

But it stll wont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put input type submit button within your from and make hide that button from screen if you really don't need that. Now when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> it would post your form data.

```
  Example:  
      <input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: are you sure you want to reload the whole page any time user press <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Better solution would be to add this event to inputs in your form:

```
$(function(){
    $('.enter > input, textarea, select').keyup(function(evt){
        if(evt.which == 13) {
            $('.enter').submit();
        }
    });
});
```